# Digitizing value to "floor" bin python

Tags: python, numpy, digitization

I need to digitize some values such that the index returned is the "floor" or "ceiling" bin.

E.g., for `bins = numpy.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0])` and a value `0.2` I expect the index to be `0`, for a value `0.26` the index returned should be `1`, 
and so on.

I have the following ugly looking function to do what I want:

```
import numpy

def get_bin_index(value, bins):
    bin_diff = bins[1]-bins[0]
    index = numpy.digitize(value, bins)
    if bins[index] - value > bin_diff/2.0:
        index -= 1
    return index
```

Is there any neat (read better/efficient) way to do this?

---

Edit: Including timing values (just satisfying my curiosity!)

```
In [1]: def get_bin_index(value, bins):
    ...:     bin_diff = bins[1]-bins[0]
    ...:     index = numpy.digitize(value, bins)
    ...:     if bins[index] - value > bin_diff/2.0:
    ...:         index -= 1
    ...:     return index
    ...:

In [2]: def get_bin_index_c(value, bins):
    ...:     return numpy.rint((value-bins[0])/(bins[1]-bins[0]))
    ...:

In [3]: def get_bin_index_mid_digitized(value, bins):
    ...:     return numpy.digitize(0.6, (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])/2.0)
    ...:

In [4]: bin_halfs = numpy.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0])

In [5]: %timeit get_bin_index(0.9, bin_halfs)
The slowest run took 5.71 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 4.93 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit get_bin_index_c(0.9, bin_halfs)
The slowest run took 14.60 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.34 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit get_bin_index_mid_digitized(0.9, bin_halfs)
The slowest run took 4.09 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.37 µs per loop
```

Comment: Do you have those values in an array?

Comment: no, the values are individual elements

Comment: So, without any loop involved, seems like would be efficient already.

Comment: Well! Though values are individual elements, I run this thousands of times. So, I was wondering if it can be made efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bin_diffs are all the same, you can do this in constant time by:

```
def get_bin_index2(value, bins):
    return numpy.rint((value - bins[0])/(bins[1]-bins[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the mid of bins and use with [`np.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) -

```
np.digitize(value, (bins[1:] + bins[:-1])/2.0)
```